# Lambda expressions from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, lambda

i am trying to do this in lambda :

**Select Hint from [tablename] where Answer = 'answer';**

this is what i have tried so far :

```
    public ModelSQL.puzzlecontent GetAcrossClue(string answer)
    {

        return context.puzzlecontents.Where(c => c.Answer.Equals(answer)).Select( g => new {g.Hint});
    }
```

Error says :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'iStellar.ModelSQL.puzzlecontent'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Comment: what is `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`? This type should be made clear.

Comment: ModelSQL is the folder name where all my CRUD class file is , puzzlecontent is the name of the CRUD class file that i am using

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `puzzlecontents`.

Comment: By using new `new {g.Hint}` you're returning an IEnumerable<> of an anonymous type (what type ever g.Hint is), this doesnt match the signature of the return type of the method (`ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`). You'll have to select something of type ModelSQL.puzzlecontent and use First/Single(OrDefault) on the result to match the signature of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `Select` returns a colection and your method returns a single instance.

Assuming that `g.Hint` is a `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent` instance, you should add `FirstOrDefault` at the end to retrieve a single item.

Something that I missed is that you're trying to return an anonymous type trough `new { g.Hint }` , that's not valid. You need to return a concrete type.

Again, Assuming that `g.Hint` is a `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent` instance, you should have

```
return context.puzzlecontents
    .Where(c => c.Answer.Equals(answer))
    .Select(g => g.Hint)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i've add FirstOrDefault() at the end . it says Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'iStellar.ModelSQL.puzzlecontent'

Comment: i am sorry but whats concrete type?

Comment: @user2376998 You probably haven't changed `g => new {g.Hint}` to `g => g.Hint`

Comment: I tried that earlier before . just i have added ToString() to the Where because they said cannot convert type string but it came another error whereby 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Hint'.

Comment: @user2376998: you need to return `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`, not an anonymous type nor a string

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I think the OP wants to get the `Hint` of the `answer`, so you should correct the return value to `string` instead of `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`. Otherwise we have to append `FirstOrDefault()` right after `Where` without any `Select`.

Comment: @King King: might be possible, but I assume that consumers of that method are expecting a `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`... at this point I'm really confused ;)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi that's the fault of the OP, he doesn't seem to know what he wants. Or we can perform 2 steps. Get the `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent` first (as required by the OP's method), then if he wants to get the `Hint`, just access `result.Hint`.

Comment: sorry i tot i was clear . what i wanted is to select hints from dbtable where answer = 'answer' , sorry for bad english

Comment: @user2376998 but your method returns `ModelSQL.puzzlecontent`? If your `Hint` is string, that method should return `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public var GetAcrossClue(string answer)
{

    return context.puzzlecontents.Where(c => c.Answer.Equals(answer)).Select( g => new {g.Hint});
}
```

ignore this part, thanks claudio. It's late what can I say?

or

```
public ModelSQL.puzzlecontent GetAcrossClue(string answer)
{

    return context.puzzlecontents.Where(c => c.Answer.Equals(answer)).Select( g => new puzzlecontent{property1 = value,property2 = etc});
}
```

this part'll work though ^

Comment: I'm afraid you can't return `var`. That won't even compile.